How to get chat_id of chat in telegram?
Im using Pyrogram and Telegram Client API and i want to write program that will send messages to chats by using Pyrogram send_message() function. How can i get a unique identifier (int) of the target chat?
I tried to use peer id from browser developer console (f12), but when i put it inside the script it gives error: ValueError: Peer id invalid.

I asked ChatGPT to solve my problem and it worked:
def get_ids():  
with app:
    dialogs = app.get_dialogs()
    # Loop through all the dialogs (chats)
    for dialog in dialogs:
        chat = dialog.chat
        print(f"Chat ID: {chat.id}, Title: {chat.title or chat.first_name or chat.username}")


From the Docs, send_message returns a Message object, you can get the group id by the .media_group_id parameter.
message = ...
group_id = message.media_group_id or None


In order to run send_message() you need chat_id parameter. Where to find it?
